# How do I add a data attribute to a Rails radio_button?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm trying to do this in a helper:

```
  def radio_button_by_code(da_form, da_field, product_id, option_code)
    txt = Product.find(product_id).options.find_by_code(option_code).title
    btn = da_form.radio_button(da_field, txt, :data-product-id => product_id)
    "<label>#{btn} #{txt}</label>".html_safe
  end
```

But, if I do that, I always get a undefined local variable or method `product' error.

If I remove the :data-product-id => product_id part, then it outputs the radio button correctly.

How can I add the data attribute to the radio_button?

Comment: what if you do: `:"data-product-id"`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:
`"data-product-id" => product_id`

Comment: which is what I wrote in comments

Comment: Sorry, I saw your comment only after.